# Will TCS India block my profile for lifetime if I accept offer and didn't join as I have good offer from another company

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, india, developer

I have received an offer letter from TCS Pune and I have accepted their offer.
Because if I don't accept in 7 days, it will be cancelled.
Now I have some other company good offer over TCS without variable pay.

If I don't join TCS, will they block my profile for a lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

**Because if I don't accept in 7 days, it will be canceled.**

No, if you haven't accepted the offer then you don't have to worry about that. But if you accept an offer and then you don't show up on your job because you got a job elsewhere then your profile will be blocked forever in their database. If the recruiter team calls you for asking that "are you going to accept our offer or not? if no, why not?". Then as an answer, you should say "I have already accepted the offer of another company but I still want to join in future at your company". you might get a counteroffer for the future if they have seen any potential in you but they definitely won't block your profile. but remember this can only happen if you don't accept the offer. If you accept the offer then there is no going back.

Think about it if you do jobs in another company at some post and go to the TSC for the job you might get a senior post if you are skilled enough. they will be happy to have you on their team as a senior post.

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that if you quit TCS to move to another company, your profile is blocked for a few years. This is because TCS found that a lot of their employees jump to another company for better pay, but then shortly (maybe within a year) try to rejoin TCS again after experiencing a bad workplace. Thus, there is currently a policy of not re-hiring ex-employees.

This is ofcourse for employees who have already worked for some years with the company.